# How to display the number with thousands comma separators without disappearing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, display, separator

i'm making currency changing calculator. input type in HTML is 'text'
`<input type="text" value="0.00" id="from-input" />` like this.

i've tried converting input value to with thousands comma separators like
`fromInput.value = amount.toLocaleString("en-US");`
but there is a problem that the number disappears when the number exceeding the thousand units is entered.
How can i display the number with thousands comma separators without number disappearing?

```
function convert(type) {
  let amount = 0;
  if (type == "from") {
    amount = parseFloat(fromInput.value); // number
    let convertedAmount = amount * currencyRatio[fromCurrency][toCurrency]; //number
    toInput.value = convertedAmount.toLocaleString("en-US"); //string
    fromInput.value = amount.toLocaleString("en-US"); //string
  } else {
    amount = parseFloat(toInput.value);
    let convertedAmount = amount * currencyRatio[toCurrency][fromCurrency];
    fromInput.value = convertedAmount;
  }
}
```

this is whole JS code

```
let currencyRatio = {
  USD: {
    KRW: 1227.6,
    USD: 1,
    GBP: 0.76,
    EUR: 0.92,
    unit: "Dollar",
  },

  KRW: {
    KRW: 1,
    USD: 0.00081,
    GBP: 0.00062,
    EUR: 0.00074,
    unit: "Won",
  },

  GBP: {
    KRW: 1620.47,
    USD: 1.32,
    GBP: 1,
    EUR: 1.21,
    unit: "Pound",
  },

  EUR: {
    KRW: 1343.13,
    USD: 1.09,
    GBP: 0.83,
    EUR: 1,
    unit: "Euro",
  },
};

const fromBtn = document.querySelector("#from-button");
const fromList = document.querySelectorAll("#from-currency-list a");
const toBtn = document.querySelector("#to-button");
const toList = document.querySelectorAll("#to-currency-list a");
const fromInput = document.querySelector("#from-input");
const fromInputDisplay = document.querySelector("#from-input-display");
const toInput = document.querySelector("#to-input");
const toInputDisplay = document.querySelector("#to-input-display");

let fromCurrency = "USD";
let toCurrency = "USD";

fromList.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fromBtn.innerText = item.innerText;
    fromCurrency = item.innerText;
    fromInputDisplay.innerText = currencyRatio[item.innerText]["unit"];
    convert("from");
  });
});

toList.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toBtn.innerText = item.innerText;
    toCurrency = item.innerText;
    toInputDisplay.innerText = currencyRatio[item.innerText]["unit"];
    convert("from");
  });
});


function convert(type) {
  let amount = 0;
  if (type == "from") {
    amount = parseFloat(fromInput.value); // number
    let convertedAmount = amount * currencyRatio[fromCurrency][toCurrency]; //number
    toInput.value = convertedAmount.toLocaleString("en-US"); //string
    fromInput.value = amount.toLocaleString("en-US"); //string
  } else {
    amount = parseFloat(toInput.value);
    let convertedAmount = amount * currencyRatio[toCurrency][fromCurrency];
    fromInput.value = convertedAmount;
  }
}

fromInput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  convert("from");
});

fromInput.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fromInput.value = "";
});

toInput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  convert("to");
});

toInput.addEventListener("click", () => {
  toInput.value = "";
});
```

this is whole HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Currency Exchange</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="rel" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="exchange-box">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" id="from-button">USD</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="from-currency-list">
          <a href="#">USD</a>
          <a href="#">KRW</a>
          <a href="#">GBP</a>
          <a href="#">EUR</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-area">
        <input type="text" value="0.00" id="from-input" />
        <div class="display" id="from-input-display">dollar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>=</h1>
    <div class="exchange-box">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" id="to-button">USD</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="to-currency-list">
          <a href="#">USD</a>
          <a href="#">KRW</a>
          <a href="#">GBP</a>
          <a href="#">EUR</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-area">
        <input type="text" value="0.00" id="to-input" />
        <div class="display" id="to-input-display">dollar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `parseFloat` won't work with thousands separators.

Comment: I recommend you use two different functions, not a `convert` function with a `type` flag.